# (uint256(keccak 256(block.blockhash(b) make an ethereal dice game with hash?

Tags: solidity

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa65d59708838581520511d98fb8b5d1f76a96cad#code

Ether system gets 50 numbers in 100 figures and  (Fixed_value = (17) Compare with Process according to result

Get the code and:
Contract owner full

```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

library Deck {
    // returns random number from 0 to 51
    // let's say 'value' % 4 means suit (0 - Hearts, 1 - Spades, 2 - Diamonds, 3 - Clubs)
    //           'value' / 4 means: 0 - King, 1 - Ace, 2 - 10 - pip values, 11 - Jacket, 12 - Queen

    function deal(address player, uint8 cardNumber) internal returns (uint8) {
        uint b = block.number;
        uint timestamp = block.timestamp;
        return uint8(uint256(keccak256(block.blockhash(b), player, cardNumber, timestamp)) % 52);

additional:

Fixed_value = (17)
payment = 2.07


if (uint256(keccak256(block.blockhash(b) ==Fixed_value {
true
      total= Player's ether * payment;
        ether Send to player account;

if (uint256(keccak256(block.blockhash(b) ==Fixed_value {
  false
     Stop
}
}
```

Comment: Hi there - can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: hi My question :

"Return uint8 (uint256 (block.blockhash (b), player, cardNumber, timestamp)) 52%);
I want to randomly generate 52 numbers and I want to compare it with fixed "Fixed_value = (17)" 17.

If the saddle 17 is in 52 different numbers, the player wins and the "payment = 2.07" player's money is multiplied and sent, how do we do it?
And how do we add a fully authorized owner to Contract?